# Hovering doesn't fill in entire background color of the region/block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When hovering over my `li` elements the background doesn't highlight the whole desired region, instead, it only highlights a small/narrow portion. How can I get the background color to highlight the entire block of element?

Here is my CSS:

```
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    background: #16A085;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"><span>Misc</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the "desired" region? You are applying the background on the hover of the a element, not the li

Comment: What do you want it to highlight? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @code4pi I changed it to the li and it still doesn't highlight the entire block and I am not sure why.

Comment: @fruitoftheloins I want it to highlight the entire block instead of just a small region.

Comment: I included an image of how it currently looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by `glyphicon` icons, to fix it add `glyphicon` icon classes to `<span>` tags instead of `<a>` tags, like this:

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: #16A085;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"> Portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Misc</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. Probably simplest would be giving it some padding instead of using line height, which would make it highlight more area.

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```